¿Cómo aplicar formato de string a un número decimal double?
la pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo darle formato a un número que contiene muchos decimales para que solo me muestre los 4 primeros decimales con la parte entera intacta?
Lo que quiero es conseguir que cuando salen decimales no tengan una largada de más de 4 decimales en el siguiente código de visual basic.


Public Function BytesToShortUnitString(ByVal NumBytes As Long) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim NewBytes As String = vbNullString
    Dim Y As Double = 0

    If NumBytes >= 1024 Then
        If NumBytes >= 1048576 Then
            If NumBytes >= 1073741824 Then
                Y = (NumBytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                NewBytes = Y & " GigaBytes"
            Else
                Y = (NumBytes / 1024 / 1024)
                NewBytes = Y & " MegaBytes"
            End If
        Else
            Y = NumBytes / 1024
            NewBytes = Y & " KiloBytes"
        End If
    Else
        NewBytes = NumBytes & " Bytes"
    End If

    BytesToShortUnitString = NewBytes
End Function



Así la variable Y es la que le quiero dar formato de máximo 4 decimales conservando la parte entera intacta.

Para formatear número puedes usar formatos preestablecidos como F o N
"1234.4567".ToString("F2") ' 1234,45  (sin separador de miles)
"1234.4567".ToString("N2") ' 1.234,45 (con separador de miles)

Donde el número que precede al formato indica la cantidad de decimales
Public Function BytesToShortUnitString(NumBytes As Long) As String
    If NumBytes < 1024 Then Return BytesToShortString(NumBytes, 1) & " Bytes"
    If NumBytes < 1048576 Then Return BytesToShortString(NumBytes, 1024) & " KiloBytes"
    If NumBytes < 1073741824 Then Return BytesToShortString(NumBytes, 1048576) & " MegaBytes"
    Return BytesToShortString(NumBytes, 1073741824) & " GigaBytes"
End Function

Private Function BytesToShortString(NumBytes As Long, Factor As Integer) As String
    Return (NumBytes / Factor).ToString("F4")
End Function


Con ToString("N4") ya me funciona. Gracias por resolverme la duda.
